# Blazor Server: redirect to login and facilitate register page

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I've got a Blazor Server web application where all the pages require to be authenticated except the login page. Whenever you're not authenticated you should be redirected to the login page.

I've achieved this with my App.razor:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeView>
                <Authorized>
                    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
                </Authorized>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <LoginPage />
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <h1> 404 - Not Found</h1>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

This does exactly what I want, whenever you're not authenticated and you navigate to a random page, it redirects to the LoginPage.

The problem I'm facing is that I want to facilitate a Register page where someone can create an account. However, with the current App.Razor, if you navigate to `localhost/register`, you're redirected to the Login page (of course).

Is there a way to solve this (elegantly) within App.Razor? I'd like to prevent having to add the same logic to each page to redirect to the login page in case you're not authenticated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do it like this

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" 
               DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin /> 
                    }
                   else
                   {
                        <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
```

This is yours:

```
<NotAuthorized>
        <LoginPage />
   </NotAuthorized>
```

Pseudocode: If user is not authorized, redirect him to the login page.

This is of course wrong. The user may be already logged in, and yet not authorized. Got it ?

You can put the authorize attribute in the _Host.cshtml file, in which case the user is redirected to the login page, even before your Blazor App is rendered.
You may place the authorize attribute at the App.razor component if you like, or in the _Imports.Razor file, etc.
In order to allow anonymous access to your Register page and or others, just annotate the top of the page with: `@attribute [AllowAnonymous]`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm 90% of the way, with your solution I am now able to indeed facilitate a register page, without being automatically redirected to the Login page.

The last 10% is the following: The Login and Register page are being rendered in the 'MainLayout' style, but these should be separate pages with their own layout. I've been toying around with the App.Razor configuration, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/layouts?view=aspnetcore-3.1#specify-a-layout-in-a-component

Comment: @Flats, Would you mind marking it as the answer if it solved your problem, so others know it was useful.

Comment: Hmm.. does this work for B2C in .NET 5? I'm trying to get my app to have just one anonymous Blazor page but it always redirects to the B2C login..